# TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python

I get the error `TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

I'm pretty sure it relates to this line of code:

```
print 'Area: %s\nInventory: %s\nHealth: %s\nHunger: %s\Water: %s' % (area, str(inventory, str(health, str(hunger, str(water)))))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So which part of the error message is unclear...? Do you know what the `str` function _does_?

Comment: Now that the asker has received an answer that should resolve his/her issue, I'm flagging to close as a simple typographical error that is unlikely to help future readers because the proper usage is covered clearly in any documentation of the `str()` function, so other users who search for "`str()` takes at most 1 argument (2 given)" will probably be searching for an answer to a different issue.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah it is..! You have not closed the parenthesis properly.

```
print 'Area: %s\nInventory: %s\nHealth: %s\nHunger: %s\nWater: %s' % (area, str(inventory), str(health), str(hunger), str(water))
```

Comment: now there is a '\' before the water

Comment: It is a typo in your question. It should be "\n" which prints a new line. I edited the answer correcting the typo. Check now.